# tensorflow: recommendation system predict users without retrain the model

Tags: tensorflow

I read many recommendation system implementation in tensorflow, for example, https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/collaborative_filtering_movielens/, but most of them could only predict ratings for the known user, known user means the user used in training the model.

so for example, if the model trained with 5 users, it could only predict rating result for those 5 users.

for new users with some rating data, the model cannot make prediction without retrain the whole model.

is it possible to predict new users with some rating data without retrain the model?